# Blender crashes loading a large file without maxing out RAM nor using SWAP

Tags: blend-files

I've run Blender 2.79b on Windows 7 (16 GBytes of RAM, CORE i7-5820k, two GTX770s in SLI) where, when loading a 24 G file, not using the GPUs, the RAM is nearly maxed out to 96% and then the swap partition is used - just as expected. Running Blender on LINUX Essential OS, Blender shuts down after trying to allocate about 60% of the RAM. I tried various Distributions - Essential OS, UBUNTU 18.04 and .10, Mint...no success. At this point it seems to be a LINUX issue - but then again - maybe there is a known issue with BLENDER for Linux?
Any insight - if any exists - is greatly appreciated!
Torsten

Comment: Just to get you going, can you import/append/link individual components from 24Gb file?

Comment: Bob - thanks for chiming in! It took me a bit to get back here - at the moment it seems that I was hunting a ghost and the file might be corrupt. I have a down-scaled version of the same file that pegs out at about 13.6 GB Blender has no issues doing that (about 86% RAM loading on my machine). I'll let you know if the file is indeed corrupt.

Comment: The file was a copy from the original and came from a USB stick. Somehow it did indeed get corrupted. Blender is fine with the original file. Additionally - the file in question did also crash Blender in WINDOWS. Thanks once again for chiming in Rob - Torsten